# Working with structure objects

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I have a logic that looks like the below (Not the actual code):

```
StructureElement x;

For i in 1 to 1000

do
    x.Elem1 = 20;
    x.Elem2 = 30;
    push(x into a std::vector)   
end
```

My knowledge is that x be allocated memory only once and that the existing values will be overwritten  for every iteration.
Also, the 'x' pushed into the vector will not be affected by subsequent iterations of pushing a modified 'x'.

Am I right in my observations?

Is the above optimal? I would want to keep memory consumption minimal and would not prefer using **new**. Am I missing anything by not using **new**?

Also, I pass this vector and recieve a reference to it it another method.

And, if I were to read the vector elements back, is this right?

```
Structure element xx = mYvector.begin()
print xx.Elem1
print xx.Elem2
```

Any optimizations or different ideas would be welcome.

Comment: @MykhayloKopytonenko It is pseudo code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I right in my observations?

Yes, if the vector is `std::vector<StructureElement>`, in which case it keeps its own copies if what is pushed in.

> Is the above optimal?

It is sub-optimal because it results in many re-allocations of the vector's underlying data buffer, plus unnecessary assignments and copies. The compiler may optimize some of the assignments and copies away, but there is no reason, for example, to re-set the elements of `x` in the loop.

You can simplify it like this:

```
std:vector<StructureElement> v(1000, StructureElement{20, 30});
```

This creates a size-1000 vector containing copies of `StructureElement` with the desired values, which is what you seem to be trying in your pseudo-code.

To read the elements back, you have options. A range based for-loop if you want to iterate over all elements:

```
for (const auto& e: v):
  std::cout << e.Elem1 << " " << e.Elem2 << std::endl;
```

Using iterators,

```
for (auto it = begin(v); it != end(v); ++it)
   std::cout << it->Elem1 << it->Elem2 << std::endl;
```

Or, pass ranges in to algorithms

```
std::transform(begin(v), end(v), ....);
```

Comment: What if the (20,30) combination is variable? What if I read them at runtime?

Comment: @thenoGk Same applies. It makes no difference here.

Comment: Thanks, please give me some time to look into it.